# mapping tag to tagged union member doesn't work for specific union, only generic one

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

As a followup to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125960/6338059), I'm trying to write a generic type that maps a tag to a type that's part of a discriminated union.

The generic version given in the above answer works:

`type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never`

But I can't make my own version that's not generic over `T` (the union itself). It *does* work if I make the union type generic with a default, which I find weird.

Here's my code:

```js
interface TypeA {
  tag: "a";
  data: string;
}

interface TypeB {
  tag: "b";
  data: [number];
}

interface TypeCD {
  tag: "c" | "d";
  data: number;
}

type Union = TypeA | TypeB | TypeCD;

type DiscriminatedUnion_0<V extends Union["tag"]> = Union extends Record<"tag", V> ? Union : never;
let shouldBeTypeA_0: DiscriminatedUnion_0<"a">; // doesn't work, type 'never'

// this works
type DiscriminatedUnion_1<V extends Union["tag"], T extends Union = Union> = T extends Record<"tag", V> ? T : never;
let shouldBeTypeA_1: DiscriminatedUnion_1<"a">;

type DiscriminatedUnion_2<V extends Union["tag"], T extends Union> = T extends Record<"tag", V> ? T : never;
let shouldBeTypeA_2: DiscriminatedUnion_2<"a", Union>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique in [`DiscriminateUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50125960/6338059) uses a [distributive conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) which only works if you are checking a bare generic type parameter.  That link explains it pretty well, or you can read a [longer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383816/2887218) if you want.  The only way to get this behavior is to do the conditional on a bare generic type parameter *somewhere*.  That's why `DiscriminatedUnion_1` worked; you checked the type parameter `T`.

Luckily you don't have to play games with default type parameters to get this effect.  The generic type parameter check has to happen, but it doesn't have to be in *directly* in your final type alias.

One way to do it is to use the original `DiscriminateUnion<T, K, V>` definition and make an alias that uses it, like

```
type MyDiscriminateUnion<V extends Union["tag"]> = DiscriminateUnion<Union, "tag", V>;
```

Another way to do this, though, is to use a predefined type alias [in the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.5/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1461-L1464) called `Extract<T, U>`, which returns all constituents of a union type `T` that match another type `U`.  The definition is as follows:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;
```

With that, you can construct your `DiscriminatedUnion` without playing games with default type parameters:

```
type DiscriminatedUnion<V extends Union["tag"]> = Extract<Union, Record<"tag", V>>;
let shouldBeTypeA: DiscriminatedUnion<"a">; // TypeA, hooray!
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!