# Map types to string property

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of data types that all contain a property `dataType` and I map each one to that value:

```
interface GroupData {
    dataType: "group";
    name: string;
    people: PersonData[];
}

interface PersonData {
    dataType: "person";
    name: string;
    email: string;
    messages: MessageData[];
}

interface MessageData {
    dataType: "message";
    message: string;
    timestamp: number;
}

interface DataTypeMap {
    group: GroupData;
    person: PersonData;
    message: MessageData;
}
```

This serves my purposes, but is a little bit manual.  In my actual app I have a **lot** more data types, and they change somewhat frequently.  What I'd like is to be able to automate the process a little bit more.  So far this is as close as I've come:

```
type DataType = GroupData
    | PersonData
    | MessageData;

type DataTypeMap = {
    [(T in DataType)["dataType"]]: T;
};
```

Moderating a single union of data types is much easier than a map where keys must be of a certain value; *however* this isn't kosher in TypeScript.  I'm getting the following TS errors:

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
```

```
Cannot find name 'T'.
```

```
'DataType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

As far as I can tell these are all problems with my syntax.  I'm 90% sure you can't use `in` with unions that aren't strings and using bracket selectors in an index signature feels like a stretch.

**Is it possible to map a list of data types based on a property that all of the data types have?**

Comment: This is possible using conditional types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125893/typescript-derive-map-from-discriminated-union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close!  Here's what we want:

```
type DataTypeMap = {
    [T in DataType['dataType']]: Extract<DataType, {dataType: T}>;
};
```

`DataType` is the union of all the type interfaces.  `DataType['dataType']` is the union of all the type name string literals.

In our map, we say that the keys are those `string` names.  For each key, we want to find the corresponding `interface`.  We use `Extract` to get only the members of the union which can have `{dataType: T}`.

This resolves to:

```
type DataTypeMap = {
    group: GroupData;
    person: PersonData;
    message: MessageData;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/nWPOLm)

Comment: This is great!  `Extract` is neat!  Thanks!