# Extracting Type from TypeScript Union

Tags: typescript

I have a union type, `PromptOptions`:

```
type PromptOptions =
  | BasePromptOptions
  | BooleanPromptOptions
  | StringPromptOptions

type BasePromptOptions = {
  kind: string | (() => string)
};

type BooleanPromptOptions = { kind: 'confirm' };

type StringPromptOptions = {
  kind: 'input' | 'invisible' | 'list' | 'password' | 'text';
};
```

What I'm trying to do:

Given an arbitrary type, `type Lookup = { kind: 'invisible' }`, I want to use `type ExtractedType<T> = Extract<PromptOptions, T>` with the end result of `ExtractedType<Lookup> = StringPromptOptions`.

This works if I pass in a type that exactly matches a prompt option (`ExtractedType<{ kind: 'confirm' }> = BooleanPromptOptions`), but something like this: `ExtractedType<{ kind: 'invisible' }> = never` when I want/expect it to be `StringPromptOptions`.

Clearly this isn't correct, but I want to do something like `Extract<PromptOptions, T extends <PromptOptions['kind']>>`, I'm just not sure how (or if this is even possible).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLZmAeVQSwQOwM5QC8AsAFBRQA%20UAQgIZ4TzKobDb5kXU0IIA2EOjmYp0WXHi5UoAZWBxMOAOajWEzqTKhItBk0Ri2HAoSgBvaQGslAEwBcUPAqXKZACncBKIgD4nLipeZAC%20ANxk2uDQvAJCIobq7JJEFlA2OA5QAOQAxrgAZphwSNlQ4ZGkOtDyiipq4sn4qZbk6XaO2UpgAK7AZdRdOABumHiYAEaCAzn8Y-0y2WAMeADuCHC2M9nAEAAe-RGkFVpV0VAAogdwdLm7tgAq0QA8D-5mVwq3wM8NxpIAGigbyOUV0AEk8LFBMI-hpTJdrt8II8XuZ2plOvkcEUSmUQr5QaQAPTEqBjKA4CDDCBwMHQSG1VxwpoIz43O4op6QZ7ojJZIajcZTCD4wlAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this after realizing that `PromptOptions` was a discriminating union via the `kind` field.

I was then able to use the `DiscriminateUnion` type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750647/get-type-of-union-by-discriminant#comment101112337_48751007) to get the correct type out of `PromptOptions`:

```
type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = T extends Record<
  K,
  V
>
  ? T
  : T extends Record<K, infer U>
  ? V extends U
    ? T
    : never
  : never;

type IsBooleanPromptOptions = Extract<DiscriminateUnion<PromptOptions, 'kind', 'confirm'>, { kind: string }>;

type IsStringPromptOptions = Extract<DiscriminateUnion<PromptOptions, 'kind', 'list'>, { kind: string }>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLZmAeVQSwQOwM5QC8AsAFBRQA%20UAQgIZ4TzKobDb5kXU0IIA2EOjmYp0WXHi5UoAZWBxMOAOajWEzqTKhItBk0Ri2HAoSgBvaQGslAEwBcUPAqXKZACncBKIgD4nLipeZAC%20ANxk2uDQvAJCIobq7JJEFlA2OA5QAOQAxrgAZphwSNlQ4ZGkOtDyiipq4sn4qZbk6XaO2UpgAK7AZdRdOABumHiYAEaCAzn8Y-0y2WAMeADuCHC2M9nAEAAe-RGkFVpV0VAAImO5ikhKdLsAqjgcADwAKgA0UADSUPu7TIEKwQEAIApQL5QABq-wOECBkIA2j8ALr%20MzvOGA2wEABKEHym1e0h%20n2k0LIvmkAH5IdJHFiAQjcVACUTbK8yVAlAUIHAoI9qW06bDmYjHtIKHT3lKoI4cBBhvyGVBFcq4EcoroAJJ4WKCYQNYwpMwAUQOcDouWAryueBumDuOAeEGeb2NGjw32yGS2PvyOCKJWyvm%205namUczjqbhCvi1Z11eFqrk9TVMUAtCmttvtjudrvduFe6ZMPr92R9c2cofDkayMdc5QTQA)

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around for half an hour, I think this is not really possible.

Anyway, here is the closest I got:

```
type ExtractedType<T> = {
  [K in PromptOptions as T extends K 
    ? K[keyof K] extends infer U extends string 
      ? U
      : "0"
    : never
  ]: K
} extends infer U ? U[keyof U] : never
```

It passes the test cases for this example:

```
type T0 = ExtractedType<{ kind: 'confirm' }>;
//   ^? BasePromptOptions | BooleanPromptOptions


type T1 = ExtractedType<{ kind: 'invisible' }>;
//   ^? BasePromptOptions | BooleanPromptOptions


type T2 = ExtractedType<{ kind: string }>
//   ^? { kind: string | (() => string); }


type T3 = ExtractedType<{ kind: () => string}> 
//   ^? { kind: string | (() => string); }
```

Note that `T0` and `T1` also get `BasePromptOptions` as a result. This is because `'invisible'` and `'confirm'` both extend `{ kind: string }`.

Also note that this **will** break for more complex scenarios. Try adding another type like `BasePromptOptions` which only has a `string` and a function as type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewLZmAeVQSwQOwM5QC8AsAFBRQA%20UAQgIZ4TzKobDb5kXU0IIA2EOjmYp0WXHi5UoAZWBxMOAOajWEzqTKhItBk0Ri2HAoSgBvaQGslAEwBcUPAqXKZACncBKIgD4nLipeZAC%20ANxk2uDQvAJCIobq7JJEFlA2OA5QAOQAxrgAZphwSNlQ4ZGkOtDyiipq4sn4qZbk6XaO2UpgAK7AZdRdOABumHiYAEaCAzn8Y-0y2WAMeADuCHC2M9nAEAAe-RGkFVpV0VAAogdwdLm7tgAq0QA8D-5mrRQA2gDSUEqwRKNExQBhQB5Qfa7TIEP7SCgAfigPy%20VggIAQBWRAF1IQcIDD-jgChA4FAAKp46G2AjOOpueEUKBI8mMiiOABEAAYOYzHDgIMNSdJsY4fqEqQSaUSSWTKSzUejMRTcfzBcLTpUoroHlzUlcFLd7k9IM9zO1Mp18sTiqVyr4jgB6R1MgB6SPojAaxhSPD4gmE3o0Uk1Zx1AEZ9dcjRBHi9zRkskNRuMphAyiEHWRnW6Pfog00CNRaq4CyYtWHoA8AExRw13WMmiBmi1ZOmue3Zl0Ud1pROOdsqDzePwBeleMLlCvVcEAZjrNwbcdNCY6UBHhH8g%20UmagXdzfbX2%20HPk3Y9cE-KQA)

---

Also theoratically, a solution may be possible by converting the union to a tuple using `TuplifyUnion` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/8613630). But this type should not be used as it kind of **breaks the type** system and is not reliable. So I haven't bothered trying it.