# Discriminated type unions in typescript with lookup object

Tags: typescript, lookup-tables, discriminated-union

I have some event interface that might have different type signature, depending on what type of event it is. Let's say we have 'FizzChange' and 'BuzzChange', and they both extend 'EventTypeBase'

```
interface EventTypeBase {
  id: string;
  timestamp: string;
}

interface FizzChange extends EventTypeBase {
  name: 'fizz';
  payload: string;
}

interface BuzzChange extends EventTypeBase {
  name: 'buzz';
  payload: number;
}
```

Now that we defined it, we can use it in function, and with conditional statement check what type we are working with

```
const mapEventsWithIfs = (event: EventType) => {
  // This works, typescript can see what type we want to use
  if (event.name === 'fizz') {
    return event.payload; // Typescript can see that this is a string
  }

  if (event.name === 'buzz') {
    return event.payload; // And this is a number
  }

  return;
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve, is that instead of if statements, I want to use a lookup object, where each type gets its own handler function, but that doesn't work. How can I type lookup object, in a way that will work?

[Here is a link to reproduce it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgCoE8AOEAQnAM4oDeAUMssACYBcypYUoA5gNw3JjABbCKzgD8zVuxDcqAXypVQkWIhQAxYAC9NAYQAWcaSggAPSCHqk0mHAWJlKvEKIjMA5DC2a3PWvji4ADYA9nBMLGycPPKK4NDwSMhEAK7a%20oYcxmZYltZYYHiEJOTI1LTOQu4ARqnevsj%20QaHhIMkCVdDRCmB2ebaEyAC8yBppBkbIAD5JtelGPFQIwSCsfWAAEob0gdCkALJw%20EOlvB5ebswAFBA2YMyjuuOZAJRDAHzIN-kAdI0hYQAaU41bQXZDXW7MFJjDIQV6DD5fcC-AL-ehyBRLFZgZACQ4YfKkADqwDAegAkjArMMIflmAT%20nD3idaAB6VnIbB6YBWADuwSgAGtSAC%20HZSAh2PgcQhDCwICheQYcT0BrzFYYVcFkMlyLxgDBwUiwN8KihBhbkGdQa8yrRkFAIGBklAQJ9biimmEuMh2ZzxZLgNLkLK3eQUGS4CruVYecg4BEpBxeDFaAajR6zUNLW4Qd5bbxaI7na73T8-s0fX6AIIWPgxuhWBOtdrQFMKItOl0gLqLZarPH4BlgakZulrQpMhEs30crlx%20jBYQgNw4-lC0XG5CZEcOiD0ZJIKxgbUgL5QXg1qAcNr5ZDBQ2qlBuYeTtyN5AgYI4sikYAcZwqh2PhtX8KAXGUe9H16Nwz0wKA3G%20S8OVoLkUCUXYIAQfhlitB45kyZAADIZhhIx315Mg9wPJB6BAq04OgNxkPtDpZV1FB8CgYJCCgHoGJcd8DCsLEYECYBsM4MVCFjMNgiEEN%2034Z1CSQtkUPtSc8K8AiIHfOMvx-Ug-wAuAgIjbUnwY89EMuAAmABmAAWABWZ5eGLbs1k2CwdigfZDgAbWNU0XAAXVpcBnmiIA)

```
const mapEvents = (event: EventType) => {
  // This doesn't work, event gets reduces to never
  // Argument of type 'EventType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  //   The intersection 'FizzChange & BuzzChange' was reduced to 'never'
  //   because property 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.
  //     Type 'FizzChange' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
  return EventHandlersMap[event.name](event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a somewhat involved approach that uses the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751007/3558960) along with a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
interface EventTypeBase {
  id: string;
  timestamp: string;
}

interface FizzChange extends EventTypeBase {
  name: 'fizz';
  payload: string;
}

interface BuzzChange extends EventTypeBase {
  name: 'buzz';
  payload: number;
}

type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>
  = T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never;

type MapDiscriminatedUnion<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T>
  = { [V in T[K]]: DiscriminateUnion<T, K, V> };

type EventType = FizzChange | BuzzChange;

type EventMap = MapDiscriminatedUnion<EventType, 'name'>;

const eventHandlersMap: {
  [K in keyof EventMap]: (event: EventMap[K]) => EventMap[K]['payload'];
} = {
  'fizz': (event: FizzChange) => event.payload,
  'buzz': (event: BuzzChange) => event.payload
}

const mapEvents = <K extends keyof EventMap>(event: EventMap[K]) => {
  const name: K = event.name;
  return eventHandlersMap[name](event);
}
```

---

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-Z5E2ogXIAAU0PyzAdpr5AEpzSDM6i+Vc3I0QmE3LdoubSrwPF43MxU37mGrdBrMrmniC0+AAHSl5qLWs1bQNlM9sDMFLqjIQTvdv39gJl+hyBRen0CVEOqwvAGEi4M3Zxgv4e5N9PxsBZu7zmu0DdgZCu5hrF4T3uu+pQCBgZJQEBfXyQMLBDKAw0LV1bgvcBs2iIA)

Answer (score 0):

Add **fizz** and **buzz** as type.

```
type ActionType = 'fizz' | 'buzz';
```

In EventHandlersMap give type to your object. So typescript will understand the object.

```
const EventHandlersMap: { [K in ActionType]: (event: ExampleEvent & any) => void } = {
    fizz: (event: FizzChange) => event.payload,
    buzz: (event: BuzzChange) => event.payload
}
```

Comment: If you make a union type with 'any', it will automatically transform this union type into 'any', so that doesn't work